# how to animate an element html with height:0px to height:auto (CSS)

Tags: css

I am trying to generate an animation by moving the mouse over my `div`, I want the `height` to be increased to the `height` it must have for its content to be fully displayed.
the effect must be from a `height(height:0px)` that starts from zero to the `total height(height:auto)` of the content

this is my code:

```css
div{
 height: 0px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 overflow: hidden;
 border:1px solid red;
}

div:hover{
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat sunt tempora, cupiditate quia labore nam quas consequuntur ducimus nemo tempore dolorem beatae voluptatem unde excepturi, error eius commodi laudantium quisquam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quo nisi, eos impedit voluptate, molestiae repudiandae ullam deserunt magnam sed aliquam eveniet id illo qui nemo vero quis officiis, veritatis.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/df973ktr/

Comment: For a Chrome & Safari-specific fix, try animating to `height: fit-content;`

Comment: You can use animation and restart it using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div:hover {
  max-height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat sunt tempora, cupiditate quia labore nam quas consequuntur ducimus nemo tempore dolorem beatae voluptatem unde excepturi, error eius commodi laudantium quisquam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quo nisi, eos impedit voluptate, molestiae repudiandae ullam deserunt magnam sed aliquam eveniet id illo qui nemo vero quis officiis, veritatis.
</div>
```

Comment: How can I dynamically get the maximum height?

Comment: or should I put a value of which I am sure I will never get over it?

Comment: You can't work with `max-height: auto;`. You have to specify a height otherwise it won't increase.

Comment: @yavg Updated my answer.